# Omitting “can” in the second clause of a complex sentence

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I am wondering whether or not I can omit the verb *can* in the following sentence:

> Students can experience different research methodologies and **can** practice teamwork on cutting-edge projects.

Comment: There is obvious scope for ambiguity, though context usually resolves this. _The girls can play badminton in the sports hall after school and practise regularly._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the second version. Skipping the second "can" definitely feels like it flows better, to me. More objectively, though, it depends on what you're trying to convey in your whole paragraph. The repetition of the "can" clearly positions your sentence as a list of 2 items. The omission of the "can", on the other hand, is more open-ended in meaning: it doesn't necessarily position the research methodologies as a distinct occurrence from the teamwork opportunities, or the cool projects, but rather as things that can happen apart, or together, or even in any combination. So if you're trying to market something (as in, "this is cool exciting stuff, and I'm only mentioning these 2 vague things, because I want to establish how dynamic and innovative all this is, before we get to details"), definitely skip the second "can". If you want to subtly manage expectations (as in, "I'm being vague now because this is very high level, but don't be surprised if you see a comparative analysis of these 2 things in the next paragraph"), you could leave it in. (Though my PERSONAL preference would still be to skip it :) )